# Hash string in Java and validate it in PHP

Tags: java, php, hash, password-hash, php-password-hash

I want to create a Java Application, which creates an user account.
After this, the user should be able to login on my website.

I need a Java method to generate a hash, which is supported by PHP.
In PHP I always used this function to generate a hash:

```
public function hashPassword($password){
  $options = [
    'cost' => 11,
  ];

  $password."<br>";
  $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."<br>";
  return $hash;
}
```

1. How can I do this in Java, when ...
2. I use this in PHP, to validate the password

   ```
    public function checkPassword($password, $hash){
       if (password_verify($passwordFromPost, $hash)) {
          echo 'Password is valid!';
      } else {
           echo 'Invalid password.';
      }
    }
   ```

PS: to generate the `$hash`, I use the first function.
If anything isn't correct, please correct my code, because I'm new in Java

Comment: What you're looking for is probably [JBCrypt](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21184/safe-to-use-jbcrypt-and-recommend-it-to-my-organization). All `password_hash` does is generate a `$2y` BCrypt. In theory you should be able to verify this with PHP

Comment: hmm, how can i hash in java with sha-256 ?

Comment: Ask that in a different question